# Multiple plugins using the same OAuth class issues

Tags: plugins, customization

I just updated a plugin that needed to be updated. The issue is they added support for OAuth, the problem this plugin and another are using the same OAuth classes. Is there a easy way to fix this? I've never messed with OAuth or classes in PHP, I'm not a programmer.

Error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code probably looks like this:

```
class OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1 {

...

}
```

It should look like this:

```
if( ! class_exists( 'OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1' ) ) :
class OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1 {

...

}
endif;
```

This is more a PHP issue than a WordPress issue, but if multiple plug-ins `include` or `require` files that declare the same class with the same name, you'll get a collision.  You only need to *define* the class once, then you can instantiate it as many times as you need in your multiple systems.

Comment: Amd let's hope that the two classes are identical, not that one of them has a newer version or worse - two different implementations that use the same classnames!